# Default privileges on Oracle database 11g

Tags: oracle11g, default, privileges, sql-grant

How can I grant default privileges to a user like in PostgreSQL like

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO PUBLIC;
```

I want to grant select, insert, update, delete to a user every time I create a new table but in Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would create a role and assign that to your user(s).

Then, every time you create a table, you would add a grant to the role.

E.g.

```
create role sample_role;

grant sample_role to example_schema;

create table new_table (col1 number, col2 varchar2(10));

grant select, insert, delete, update on new_table to sample_role;
```

Then the `example_schema` user (plus any other users who are assigned to that role) will automatically be able to select, insert, update or delete on the new table.